# Remote File Copy - Win Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote, files

I'd like to copy backup archives from a remote server to my client machine.  In the past, I've installed an FTP server on the remote machine and directed local server backups to dump into that directory.  I'd then FTP in from my client machine.

Just wondering if there is a simpler way to do this using Win 7 (Client) Win Server 2008?

Robocopy?  RDC command line options?

For example, I can easily remote desktop in and drag the files from the server to my local machine.  If there is an easy command line way to do this, then I don't have to setup an FTP server which is ideal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a VPN connection between the two systems? If so, seems like `robocopy` is about as good of a tool as any.

Comment: No VPN connection, I can install that but similar to the FTP it's an install solely for this purpose, so I was curious if there was a built in command line feature similar to what I can do through Remote Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got the solution for your requirement..but I was searching for same thing and I came across this link: Copy Configuration Files to a Remote Server (IIS 7) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770873(v=ws.10).aspx

It explains how to use `net` and `xcopy` commands to copy files to remote server.
Check if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the files, you can copy paste files over rdp. Or you can use the RDP client to map the local win7 drives and copy paste to the mapped drives.

edit: wow - didn't realize this post was so old..